# How to avoid focus a div, when it is click and dragged..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I would like to make a div focus only on onclick. Draggable works perfectly, but when i finish my drag option the div gets focused. And also i need to remove the **cursor: move** to **cursor: auto** when click on the div. Please help me..

```
$(function() {
var block = $('#text-block')
block.find('.editable-text').resizable({
    containment: $('#drag-area'),
    handles: {
        nw: block.find('.nw'),
        ne: block.find('.ne'),
        sw: block.find('.sw'),
        se: block.find('.se')
    }, 
    minWidth: 50, minHeight: 18
})
});

$(function() {
$( ".editable-text" ).draggable();
});
```

My code in [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/sLmwm2sr/25/)...!

Answer (score 0):

add the following line in your css under `.editable-text` selector

```
.editable-text {
    /*your old code*/
    outline:none;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qe6taLkg/)

Edited:
 to prevent text selection
 add `noselect` class to `noselect`
and write the following in your css file

```
.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
  -khtml-user-select: none;    /* Konqueror */
  -moz-user-select: none;      /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;       /* IE/Edge */
  user-select: none;
```

}

and also look at the jquery change for changing cursor if it what you are looking for

[Fiddle3 updated](https://jsfiddle.net/taeyr21m/)

copy this js code

```
  $(function() {
  var block = $('#text-block')
  block.find('.editable-text').resizable({
    containment: $('#drag-area'),
    handles: {
        nw: block.find('.nw'),
        ne: block.find('.ne'),
        sw: block.find('.sw'),
        se: block.find('.se')
    }, 
    minWidth: 50, minHeight: 18
  })
});

$(function() {
  $( ".editable-text" ).draggable();

 $(".editable-text").mousedown(function(e){
    if(e.which == 1) {
      $(this).css({
        'cursor':'move'
      });
            }else{
      $(this).css({
          'cursor':'auto'
        });
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. But i need to make not focus the div when at the end of my click and drag finish. Your code makes focus into the div to edit after the drag.

Comment: Now draggable not works and also cursor not get change when onclick.

Comment: check fiddle2 updated link now, i was having error in jquery code

Comment: There is no change i have seen inFiddle2 updated. It gets focus into the div when end of drag. Cursor not get change after onclick on the div.

Comment: check fiddle 3 now

Comment: Copied the code and tested.. not working.. The website [link](https://www.canva.com/) here which will show how i need.. After register in this site, add any text will show you..